# How to print the active or inactive status in excel

Tags: excel, date

I have file like

```
column1
7-Jan-07
10-May-20
15-Aug-19
.........
.........
```

but I want output like

```
column1    column2
7-Jan-07   Inactive
10-May-20  active 
15-Aug-19  active
```

Means if current date is less than `column1` date then it print `Inactive` or else it will be print as `Active` .. How to do this in Excel.? Is possible to achieve this in excel..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, you can use `IF` and `TODAY()` to get today's date (assuming that your computer time is correct). Assuming that the first date is in cell A2:

```
=IF(A2<TODAY(), "Inactive", "Active")
```

Comment: I have date fields like `1-Dec-10 30-Nov-14` how to find the difference between them?

Comment: @Ram What do you mean? You can to get the number of days between the those two dates?

Comment: I mean to find the how many years difference.. I tried like `=Year(B1)-Year(A1)` but showing `4-Jan-00`. Why it showing like this?

Comment: @Ram What happens if you format this cell as General?